# Datetime milliseconds to seconds in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Have a datetime column in pandas dataframe with values like these:

```
time
2018-04-11 22:18:30.122
2018-04-11 23:00:21.399
```

I'm wondering how can I round these values, get rid of milliseconds and represent only date, hour, minutes and 00 as seconds like this:

```
time
2018-04-11 22:18:00
2018-04-11 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) with `T` for minutes for set `0 seconds`:

```
#if necessary
#df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.floor('T')
#alternative solution
#df['time'] = df['time'].dt.floor('Min')

print (df)
                 time
0 2018-04-11 22:18:00
1 2018-04-11 23:00:00
```

I want [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) values time after `30sec` is changed to next one:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.round('T')
print (df)
                 time
0 2018-04-11 22:19:00
1 2018-04-11 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

well, [ceil](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) is also work for this question.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.ceil('T')
df
                 time
0 2018-04-11 22:19:00
1 2018-04-11 23:01:00
```