# Round seconds of a date time column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to round seconds in a dataframe column which contains date and time in the format 01Jan2019:11:03:57.541.

I want to get the result as 01Jan2019:11:03:58
The column is in object format.
Could someone please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime milliseconds to seconds in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005444/datetime-milliseconds-to-seconds-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for datetimes, then round by [`Series.dt.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) and last convert by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01Jan2019:11:03:57.541','01Jan2019:11:03:57.241']})
print (df)
                     date
0  01Jan2019:11:03:57.541
1  01Jan2019:11:03:57.241

df['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
                .dt.round('S')
                .dt.strftime('%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S'))

print (df)
                 date
0  01Jan2019:11:03:58
1  01Jan2019:11:03:57
```